# Fermenting Cow's Milk, or making Kumis

Tags: fermentation

Playing around with making my own yeast cultures, one of them has is white while fermenting. That started me thinking, "can I ferment Cow's Milk?".

One google search later there is [Kumis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumis), made from Mare Milk. But I am not sure how to go about it. This seems to be a nice list of steps:

1. Get milk.
2. Get enzyme that makes [Glucose from Lactose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk#Carbohydrates_and_miscellaneous_contents).
3. Maybe add some more glucose.
4. Add yeast to the above.
5. Maybe add yogurt culture, to use the fats and proteins.
6. Let ferment for x hours / days.
7. Strain out solid bits.
8. Enjoy drink.

**Will this work?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one wants to ferment milk with yeast and lactbacillius to make a drink (as opposed to cheese) then why not use the well known "milk kefir" grains to do the job. This form of fermented milk is well known and documented and milk kefir grains are a commercially available "SCOBY". Wikipedia has a good entry on the subject and there are many other references on the interweb.

Comment: I think milk kefir is a very good drink when made from fresh cows milk. I am not sure if I prefer the full cream or the skimmed milk variety. Milk Kefir made with full cream milk (from the farm) can sometimes be a bit lumpy or stringy - although that goes if you sieve it. The skimmed version is easy to drink but can be a bit "thin" compared to the full cream kefir.

Answer (score 1):

Milk is historically and commercially fermented with lactic acid bacteria like Lactobacillus. This process is used For everything from sour milk to cheese.

As far as making something with yeast.
Lactaid has the enzyme needed to break down the unfermentable lactose.

I really don't know what the out come would be using enzymes and yeast. Only thing that comes to mind is the"cement mixer" gag drink, mixing Bailey's Irish cream and whiskey.  Which tastes great for about a second then leaves a mouth full of curd.